# how to write Custom JSon serializer in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, jsonserializer

I am using Newtonsoft json serializer to convert json string into objects. I have json structure as below -

```
{
    "EmployeeRecords": {
        "12": {
            "title": "Mr",
            "Name": "John"
        },
        "35":{
            "title": "Mr",
            "Name": "Json"
        }
    }
}
```

I want this Json to be serilized into below class -

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeRecords
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Here Employeenumber is 12 and 35.

Please guide me how can I write custom serilizer which will read the Employee number from parent node and include it in the child node's EmployeeNumber property.

Comment: try to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: Are you required by business rules to create that JSON?  It's valid but it's very non-standard.

Comment: Can you modify the JSON? Don't reinvent the wheel! Serialize JSON in a matching class, then convert this class in the one you want.

Comment: Cannt modify JSON its provided by Business using some CQ5 tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize into a dictionary, then assign the EmployeeNumbers in a loop.

```
public class DataModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, Employee> EmployeeRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Assing the numbers after deserialization:

```
var records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(json);

foreach (var item in records.EmployeeRecords)
{
    item.Value.EmployeeNumber = item.Key;
}
```

Comment: How to deserialize to dictionary first which will populate Employee object?

Comment: @CHash_Mike Change the property name in EmployeeRecords class. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Ufuk, I tried this solution but it fails to serialize the json to dictionary. Am I missing something? I am wondering how would serializer know the json object has to be serialized to dictionary?

Comment: @CHash_Mike Objects are simply dictionaries in JavaScript. I have changed class name because you can't have property names with the same name. Can you try it again?

Comment: Thanks @Ufuk.. The solution is correct but looks like some issue with my class structure generated from Json, the collection is coming as null.

Comment: @CHash_Mike Could you solve the problem? I tested the code above and it works.

Comment: Its working now .. Thanks, i messed up with Class names.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with LINQ to JSON (`JObject` and friends). Here's a short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public JProperty ToJProperty()
    {
        return new JProperty(EmployeeNumber,
            new JObject {
                { "title", title },
                { "Name", Name }
            });
    }
}

public class EmployeeRecords
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public JObject ToJObject()
    {
        var obj = new JObject();
        foreach (var employee in Employees)
        {
            obj.Add(employee.ToJProperty());
        }
        return new JObject {
            new JProperty("EmployeeRecords", obj)
        };
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var records = new EmployeeRecords {
            Employees = new List<Employee> {
                new Employee {
                    EmployeeNumber = "12",
                    title = "Mr",
                    Name = "John"
                },
                new Employee {
                    EmployeeNumber = "35",
                    title = "Mr",
                    Name = "Json"
                },
            }
        };
        Console.WriteLine(records.ToJObject());
    }    
}
```

It may not be the *simplest* code (Ufuk's approach is great if you're happy to change your structuring), but it shows how customizable everything is.